# Robocopy become a endless loop

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a robocopy batch file in C:\batch. Here is the batch file:

```
set LOG="C:\Log\robolog.txt"
set START1="C:\WORK"
set END1="\\fs-02\Work"

Robocopy %START1% %END1% /MIR /PURGE /SEC /SECFIX /R:1 /W:5 /V /ETA /LOG:%LOG%
```

My question is if i open **cmd** from the location (c:\batch) that contains this batch file and run it from there, it just runs it over and over again and never ends....and i can not even terminate the **cmd**.... `Ctrl+C` will only speed up the loop.....

but if **cmd** start location is somewhere else, the batch file runs and finishes well.

Any idea why I CAN NOT run this robocopy batch file directly from the location that contains it?

Comment: FYI `/MIR` is already doing a `/PURGE`

Comment: Oh yeah...you are right, no need for a /purge again

Comment: How is the batch file named? robocopy?

Comment: yes， i just simply named it as robocopy, do you think that's why? @ MC ND

Comment: Yes.  it is calling itself and doing nothing.

Comment: @RootLoop, Did you manage to fix it by renaming the file?

Comment: OMG, I'm so embarassed; I had this EXACT problem.  
I forgot the programming rule:  
**NEVER EVER EVER use Keywords as names of any sort.**  
No matter how sure you are, something unexpected will happen.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### Robocopy Endless Batch Script Loop Fix

**The Cause**

If you have a Batch script with the name `Robocopy.cmd` for example, you will get an endless loop when you execute the script.

**Happened to me**

I was testing and noticed this but didn't know having the name of the script the same as the command will cause [Robocopy](https://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html) to endlessly loop. It worked from command line but looped endlessly from the batch script once it was executed.

**The Solution**

Don't have your batch script named just `Robocopy` and rename it to something different e.g. `Robocopyzzz`, `script123`, etc.

Comment: I wanted to provide a clear answer to this question since it helped me.

Comment: D'oh! This got me too.

Comment: This can also be a problem if you have robocopy.bat in the same folder (or even subfolder).

Answer (score 0):

As @MCND and @foxdrive already commented the solutin/the cause is the fact that the file have the same name as the command itself.

Answer (score 0):

Change the name of your .bat file to something else from robocopy.bat.

This happed to me as well earlier.